# How to overlay two images in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I try to overlay two images but the result is not what I want.
imag1 is a dermocopy image occluded with hair. image a hair-free image. I substract them to get the hair. When i try to reverse the operation by summimg imag1 and image 2, the result is different. the hair looks white while it is black.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Load the images
image1 = Image.open('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/Testing/hairoccluded/ISIC_0024327.jpg')
image2 = Image.open('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/Testing/hairfree/ISIC_0024327.jpg')

# Subtract image2 from image1
subtracted_image = ImageChops.subtract(image2, image1)

# Reverse the subtraction using ImageChops.add
reversed_image = ImageChops.add(image2, subtracted_image)

# Display the reversed image
reversed_image.show()
```

[[[enter image description here](https://i[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr99d.jpg)stack.imgur.com/bzo4m.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0XAO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akeor.jpg)

THe opeation image.add should be reversed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

- The math is incorrect:

`subtracted_image = ImageChops.subtract(image2, image1)`
==> subtracted_image = image2 - image1

`reversed_image = ImageChops.add(image2, subtracted_image)`
==> reversed_image = image2 + subtracted_image
==> reversed_image = image2 + (image2 - image1)
==> reversed_image = image2*2 - image1

As you can see the math is wrong.
The correct statement is:
`reversed_image = ImageChops.add(image1, subtracted_image)`
==> reversed_image = image1 + (image2 - image1)
==> reversed_image = image2

---

- The second issue is that `ImageChops.subtract` and `ImageChops.add` are **not reversible** operations.
  That is because the data type is `uint8`, and can't have negative values (and can't have values above 255).
  When using `ImageChops.subtract`, all negative values are clipped to zero.
  When using `ImageChops.add`, all values above 255 are clipped to 255.
  The clipping to range [0, 255] loses data, and we are not getting the original image.

There is a nice explanation in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663259/what-is-the-difference-between-pil-imagechops-subtract-and-first-converting-to-n).

---

We may use [ImageChops.subtract_modulo](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.subtract_modulo) and [ImageChops.add_modulo](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.add_modulo), which are reversible.
The math is not intuitive, but it's working:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Load the images
image1 = Image.open('image1.jpg')
image2 = Image.open('image2.jpg')

# Subtract image2 from image1
subtracted_image = ImageChops.subtract_modulo(image1, image2)  # image1 - image2

reversed_image = ImageChops.add_modulo(image2, subtracted_image)  # image2 + (image1 - image2)

# Display the reversed image
reversed_image.show()
```

---

More intuitive solution is converting the images to NumPy arrays with type dtype `np.int32` or `np.int16`.
Then subtract and add the NumPy arrays.
The advantage is that `np.int32` or `np.int16` types may hold positive and negative values, and have a larger range that avoids arithmetic overflow.